# Webpacker can't find hello_react.js

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I am setting up a new react with rails (learning) application but can't get past this error. I am using rails 6. I have `webpacker` installed and setup in my app.

I am getting error at this line in my `application.html.erb`

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_react' %>
```

When i hit `/` i get this error:

```
Webpacker can't find hello_react.js in /Users/apple/www/projects/react/example/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-3dd0dc24d9c39bc09227.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-3dd0dc24d9c39bc09227.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-3dd0dc24d9c39bc09227.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-3dd0dc24d9c39bc09227.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please guide me on what i might be doing wrong? I have removed node_modules and re-installed `webpack` and `yarn` in my application but the error persists.

Comment: Your problem is locally? Did you run de dev command line for hot update?

Comment: Yes localhost error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to run `bin/webpack-dev-server` as described on the [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/webpacker.html#hot-module-replacement-hmr)

I think your problem is a mapping problem that will be solve locally with this.

Do not forget add the requirement of `hello_react.js` on your `packs` folder in case you're using it.